# Routes passport-local

Tags: node.js, express, routes, passport-local

I am trying to use passport-local to restrict access of a website.
For this I am using login_app for running passport-local, however this is in itself a route that is called from the main app.js.
While trying to route on a 2nd level (passport-files/routes) I find that my code is found, but the functions inside are not called.
This is my login_app code:

```
var express       = require('express');
var router        = express.Router();
var mongoose      = require ('mongoose');
var flash         = require('connect-flash');
var passport      = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var morgan        = require('morgan');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var session       = require('express-session');

let app = express();

// pass passport for configuration
require('./passport-files/passport')(passport); 

//For express application
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

//Initialize passport session
app.use(session({ secret: 'secret' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


// load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport
require('./passport-files/routes')(app, passport);

module.exports = router;
```

To simplify the question I am only putting the routes.js file here:

```
var express       = require('express');
var router        = express.Router();

let app = express();
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
//function views (app, passport) {

/* GET users listing. */
// HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login-welcome', {});
});

// LOGIN ===============================
// show the login form
app.get('/log-in', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
});

// process the login form
app.post('/log-in', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/admin', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/log-in', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));

// we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    res.render('profile', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
}); 
};

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

// if they aren't redirect them to the hosme page
res.redirect('/');   

};
```

I pretty much built this using the example from scotch.io ( https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local ), however I cannot get it to work this way.
If i write the routes directly into login_app, they are recognized, even though the authentification still does not work.

Do any of you have an idea how to solve this? Is more information required?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the problem: in your login_app module you're exporting `router`, however you haven't actually defined any routes on `router`, they're all defined on a new instance of an `app`.

A simple example creating a router in one file, and exporting it to use in a main `app.js` file, would be like this:

```
/** app.js */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var myRoutes = require('./routes');
app.use(myRoutes);
app.listen(3000);


/** routes.js */
// instaniate a new router, add routes/middleware on it, and export it
var router = require('express').Router();
// define your routes and middleware here
// router.use( ... )
module.exports = router;
```

Another pattern, which I think the scotch.io tutorial is using, is to have the routes file export a function into which you pass your main app instance. Then the two files would look like this:

```
/** app.js */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('./routes')(app); // pass your main `app` instance into the function
app.listen(3000);


/** routes.js */
module.export = function(app) {
  // define all your routes and middleware here directly on the `app` that gets passed in
  // app.use( ... )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I solved the problem I had, which was the use of app as 2 different app, and manage to solve it by just switching to router. Thanks for the help